# Docker container visible on localhost but not from other hosts with custom bridge0

Tags: networking, docker, ipv6, iptables, connection-timeout

### New Docker 1.7.0 Install on RHEL 7.1

So, I installed the latest Docker 1.7.0 and I cannot get this new server to serve to the outside world.

```
[root@pppdc9prd8ok eea.docker.jenkins]# uname -a
Linux pppdc9prd8ok 3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Apr 24 15:26:38 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@pppdc9prd8ok eea.docker.jenkins]# docker --version
Docker version 1.7.0, build 0baf609
[root@pppdc9prd8ok eea.docker.jenkins]# docker info
Containers: 10
Images: 110
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-253:0-4374531-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 4.398 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 99.18 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 7.029 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.14 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Data loop file: /app_local/var-lib-docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /app_local/var-lib-docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.93-RHEL7 (2015-01-28)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64
Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 15.52 GiB
Name: pppdc9prd8ok
ID: 3M2F:QYY7:Z5DI:YTVI:RAV4:SHPM:C3RC:CWIY:FHFA:ZYAS:SNHG:CMTY
```

### Setup Docker with bridge0 instead of docker0

I followed the advanced networking topics on Docker documentation to [change my default docker bridge from docker0 to bridge0](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#building-your-own-bridge) due to a conflict to our internal network.

I started a docker container running on port 80 using docker-compose.yml as follows:

```
[root@pppdc9prd8ok eea.docker.jenkins]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
a9f5637552ba        eeacms/jenkins:master   "/usr/local/bin/jenk   4 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp   eeadockerjenkins_master_1
c6fcac33b044        yorkshirekev/postfix    "/bin/bash -c '/star   7 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds                                                         eeadockerjenkins_postfix_1
199ad3d48dfe        eeacms/jenkins:slave    "/bin/sh -c /bin/jen   5 minutes ago       Up 47 seconds                                                        eeadockerjenkins_worker_1
3a8057253b7d        eeacms/jenkins:slave    "/bin/sh -c /bin/jen   5 minutes ago       Up 47 seconds                                                        eeadockerjenkins_worker_2
fced8be92258        eeacms/jenkins:slave    "/bin/sh -c /bin/jen   5 minutes ago       Up 46 seconds                                                        eeadockerjenkins_worker_3
7cb4cfabd3c2        mongo                   "/entrypoint.sh mong   2 weeks ago         Up 20 seconds       0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp                         mongodb-dotci
```

### Server on port 80 cannot be accessible from the Internet

From what is printed by "ps", the service running on port 80 is perfectly fine, bound to the all ip address 0.0.0.0 on port 80. However, trying to access this machine from another location I am unable.

```
Marcello-New2015:~ mdesales$ curl http://docker.corp.intuit.net/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to docker.corp.intuit.net port 80: Operation timed out
```

### There are routes internally from localhost

Weird, because I have already checked that the container is accessible from inside and it is working.

```
[root@pppdc9prd8ok eea.docker.jenkins]# curl localhost | grep html
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 26791  100 26791    0     0   110k      0 --:    <!DOCTYPE html><html><head resURL="/static/9ebca566">
--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  110k
```

### Netstat also shows it is bound to ipv6.

I guess RHEL 7.1 has ipv6 configured out of the box because I haven't set it up during installation. Anyway, that's showing me... I was digging around, the :::* for ipv6 is the same as 0.0.0.0 for ipv4.

```
[root@pppdc9prd8ok eea.docker.jenkins]#  netstat -tulnp | grep docker
tcp6       0      0 :::27017                :::*                    LISTEN      18271/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      18498/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::50000                :::*                    LISTEN      18490/docker-proxy
```

And the iptables shows the rules for forwarding the calls properly to the interfaces.

### ifconfig and iptables has all the interfaces correctly showing

```
[root@pppdc9prd8ok eea.docker.jenkins]# ifconfig
bridge0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.5.1  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 192.168.7.255
        ether 1e:dd:74:96:b1:c5  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10551  bytes 10704512 (10.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9986  bytes 10375991 (9.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.42.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether 00:00:00:00:00:00  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 54772  bytes 61032436 (58.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 53436  bytes 61653718 (58.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.132.52.146  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 10.132.55.255
        ether 00:50:56:01:0e:ba  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 117543  bytes 12322742 (11.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 626  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21044  bytes 3662343 (3.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The ip tables has the rules:

```
[root@pppdc9prd8ok eea.docker.jenkins]# iptables -t nat -nxvL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 82 packets, 10381 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      23     1412 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 52 packets, 6951 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 330 packets, 29005 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 330 packets, 29005 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      21     1548 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !bridge0  192.168.4.0/22       0.0.0.0/0
      15     1028 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       192.168.4.5          192.168.4.5          tcp dpt:27017
       0        0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       192.168.4.8          192.168.4.8          tcp dpt:50000
       0        0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       192.168.4.8          192.168.4.8          tcp dpt:8080

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 DNAT       tcp  --  !bridge0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:27017 to:192.168.4.5:27017
       0        0 DNAT       tcp  --  !bridge0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:50000 to:192.168.4.8:50000
       8      512 DNAT       tcp  --  !bridge0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 to:192.168.4.8:8080
```

Not sure where to go :( Help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer: remove "docker0" bridge when installing "bridge0"!

OK, so digging more and more I found out that the presence of docker0 interferes with the networking somehow...

### Long answer: step-by-step verification

I first verified that the bridge0 is in fact being used. And IT WAS NOT!

```
[root@pppdc9prd8ok eea.docker.jenkins]# systemctl status docker
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─http-proxy.conf
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2015-07-10 07:23:14 UTC; 30min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 18034 (docker)
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           ├─18034 /usr/bin/docker -d -H fd://
           ├─18271 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 27017 -container-ip 192.168.4.5 -container-port 27017
           ├─18490 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 50000 -container-ip 192.168.4.8 -container-port 50000
           └─18498 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 80 -container-ip 192.168.4.8 -container-port 8080

Jul 10 07:23:57 pppdc9prd8ok docker[18034]: time="2015-07-10T07:23:57.124143415Z" level=info msg="GET /v1.18/containers/json?all=0&limit=-1&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5...5D%7D&size=0"
Jul 10 07:23:57 pppdc9prd8ok docker[18034]: time="2015-07-10T07:23:57.126520912Z" level=info msg="GET /v1.18/containers/c6fcac33b04480970aa3606f86e5ed9571a320b6ff5cdc8ecdf81edfb416720a/json"
Jul 10 07:23:57 pppdc9prd8ok docker[18034]: time="2015-07-10T07:23:57.128362232Z" level=info msg="GET /v1.18/containers/json?all=1&limit=-1&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5...5D%7D&size=0"
Jul 10 07:23:57 pppdc9prd8ok docker[18034]: time="2015-07-10T07:23:57.130940471Z" level=info msg="POST /v1.18/containers/create?name=eeadockerjenkins_master_1"
Jul 10 07:23:57 pppdc9prd8ok docker[18034]: time="2015-07-10T07:23:57.299140678Z" level=info msg="GET /v1.18/containers/a9f5637552bad2d608f838cdb2a263452f5e98962c45ebe759ed0904211d6962/json"
Jul 10 07:23:57 pppdc9prd8ok docker[18034]: time="2015-07-10T07:23:57.301413002Z" level=info msg="POST /v1.18/containers/a9f5637552bad2d608f838cdb2a263452f5e98962c45ebe759ed0904211d6962/start"
Jul 10 07:23:57 pppdc9prd8ok docker[18034]: time="2015-07-10T07:23:57.504799799Z" level=info msg="DELETE /v1.18/containers/0665b35b4f1df8e8d098a429ae4a057a91c36cc341d33f710b00cc3c4...alse&v=False"
Jul 10 07:23:58 pppdc9prd8ok docker[18034]: time="2015-07-10T07:23:58.657884948Z" level=info msg="GET /v1.18/containers/json?all=0&limit=-1&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5...5D%7D&size=0"
Jul 10 07:24:01 pppdc9prd8ok docker[18034]: time="2015-07-10T07:24:01.793020916Z" level=info msg="GET /v1.19/containers/json"
Jul 10 07:43:25 pppdc9prd8ok docker[18034]: time="2015-07-10T07:43:25.850272360Z" level=info msg="GET /v1.19/info"
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

It turns out that RHEL 7.1 installs Docker with the service upstart without pointing to the Environment variables.

```
[root@pppdc9prd8ok eea.docker.jenkins]# cat /etc/sysconfig/docker
# /etc/sysconfig/docker
#
# Other arguments to pass to the docker daemon process
# These will be parsed by the sysv initscript and appended
# to the arguments list passed to docker -d

other_args="-b=bridge0"
```

I had to add the line **EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker** in the following file and add the environment variable to the "docker -d" command:

```
[root@pppdc9prd8ok eea.docker.jenkins]# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network.target docker.socket
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d $other_args -H fd://
MountFlags=slave
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
LimitCORE=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Restart the docker service now shows the docker0 parameter in the system.

```
[root@pppdc9prd8ok eea.docker.jenkins]# systemctl status docker
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─http-proxy.conf
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2015-07-10 07:23:14 UTC; 30min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 18034 (docker)
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           ├─18034 /usr/bin/docker -d -b=bridge0 -H fd://
           ├─18271 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 27017 -container-ip 192.168.4.5 -container-port 27017
           ├─18490 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 50000 -container-ip 192.168.4.8 -container-port 50000
           └─18498 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 80 -container-ip 192.168.4.8 -container-port 8080
```

However, the service was still not working... The last thing I checked and I got it to work was removing the bridge "docker0". AND IT WORKED!!!

```
[root@pppdc9prd8ok eea.docker.jenkins]# ip link set docker0 down
[root@pppdc9prd8ok eea.docker.jenkins]# brctl delbr docker0
[root@pppdc9prd8ok eea.docker.jenkins]# ifconfig
bridge0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.5.1  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 192.168.7.255
        ether 16:1b:b8:42:5c:9e  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6550  bytes 6542448 (6.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6133  bytes 6585941 (6.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.132.52.146  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 10.132.55.255
        ether 00:50:56:01:0e:ba  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 114644  bytes 11944039 (11.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 626  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19671  bytes 2808015 (2.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Testing it from the other host now worked properly!

```
Marcello-New2015:~ mdesales$ curl http://docker.corp.intuit.net/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 26804  100 26804    0     0  60458      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 60505
```